# Passing an id value into a URL

Tags: javascript, facebook, url, query-string

My company hosts user created surveys on our server.  When they are uploaded, they are given a key number as an identifier.  I am trying to create a facebook app that people can post a simple survey to and distribute.  I can set the canvas URL to the default URL of our server, but I need to pass that key to the query string at the end of the app URL.

```
<input type="hidden" id="SurveyKey" name="SurveyKey" value="130633791306">
```

so, the end link needs to be apps.facebook.com/myappname/130633791306
or apps.facebook.com/myappname/SurveyKey value

I am very new to JavaScript and didn't know if there was some get function that could just pull that from the source code and pass it into a new URL.  I'm sure this is something easy, but as I am not sure how to word my question, my search result is coming up with a lot of unrelated material.

The URLs for our surveys look like this:

http://www.snapsurveys.com/swh/surveylogin.asp?k=130633791306

where k is a unique value for every survey.  I want to be able to pull that value from the source code and pass it into the URL of my facebook app (which has the canvas URL set as our URL).  So, it would look like apps.facebook.com/appname/k=VALUE_HERE

Comment: Do you want to redirect to the FB url from within the page that contains that input tag?

Comment: Yes. I want a button that just pops it over to the facebook canvas set by that app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the query string in JavaScript you could use a code snipet like this:

```
function querySt(ji) {
    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");
    for (i=0;i<gy.length;i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Then you just define a variable to store the key, ie

```
var surveyKey = querySt("k");
```

Now you can use the surveyKey anywhere, so for example:

```
var url = "http://apps.facebook.com/appname/k=" + surveyKey;
```

http://ilovethecode.com/Javascript/Javascript-Tutorials-How_To-Easy/Get_Query_String_Using_Javascript.shtml

Comment: How do I get the var url into a link?  I tried document.write("<a href=....etc but that doesn't seem to do the job.  Is there any way to have href="url" where url is the variable?

Comment: document.write("<a href=\"" + url + "\">Link</a>");